# Build UI changes in JHipster microservice application

Tags: java, microservices, jhipster

I have created a microservice application using JHipster. In one of the service, I have made changes under `src/main/webapp/app` directory to change contents in the TypeScript file but I am unable to include the changes in the docker image which I am building using `./mvnw -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild` command.

This commands only builds the changes under `src/main/java` folder but not the changes under the `src/main/webapp/app` directory.

Is there any other command which I should use to build the UI changes?

Comment: The microservices in JHipster are not supposed to have a UI, it's the role of the gateway.

Comment: I have created a microservice application which includes 1 gateway and 3 backend microservices. i was talking about the 1 gateway application which I have

Comment: Webpack builds the UI, in dev you must run npm start (see https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#working-with-angular) and when you run a prod build, maven runs webpack.